# How do I fetch search results from multiple API using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, search

I am new to ReactJS and I am trying to create a search feature with react by fetching data from multiple API. Below is the **Search.js** file. I tried so many times to make it functions and make the results appear live while typing. I however keep on getting this error message ***TypeError: values.map is not a function***. Where am I going wrong and how do I fix it?

```js
function Search() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);

  const urls = [
    'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments',
    'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=1'
  ]

  Promise.all(urls.map(url => fetch(url)
    .then((values) => Promise.all(values.map(value => value.json())))
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => setResults(data))
    .catch(error => console.log('There was a problem!', error))

  ), [])

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setInput(e.target.value);
  }
  if (input.length > 0) {
    results.filter((i) => {
      return i.name.toLowerCase().match(input);
    })
  }
  return ( <
    div className = "search"
    htmlFor = "search-input" >
    <
    input type = "text"
    name = "query"
    value = {
      input
    }
    id = "search"
    placeholder = "Search"
    onChange = {
      handleChange
    }
    /> {
    results.map((result, index) => {
        return ( <
            div className = "results"
            key = {
              index
            } >
            <
            h2 > {
              result.name
            } < /h2> <
            p > {
              result.body
            } < /p> {
            result
          } <
          /div>
      )
    })

} </div>

)
}
```

```css
.search {
  position: relative;
  left: 12.78%;
  right: 26.67%;
  top: 3%;
  bottom: 92.97%;
}

.search input {
  /* position: absolute; */
  width: 40%;
  height: 43px;
  right: 384px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  top: 1.56%;
  bottom: 92.97%;
  background: rgba(0, 31, 51, 0.02);
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50px;
  float: left;
  outline: none;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  /* identical to box height */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /* Dark */
  color: #001F33;
}


/* Search Icon */

input#search {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-indent: 50px;
  background-size: 18px;
  background-position: 30px 15px;
}

input#search:focus {
  background-image: none;
  text-indent: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Try `console.loging` it with `then(res => console.log(res))`

Comment: Can you log what your response JSON object shape is?

Comment: I tried and this was the response **There was a problem! TypeError: values.map is not a function at Search.js:26 at async Promise.all (:3001/index 0)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

1. The response you get from `fetch(url)` is *just* the one single response, so there's nothing to map.
2. The data fetching occurs in the function body of the component, so when working this causes render looping since each render cycle fetches data and updates state.
3. The `input.length > 0` filtering *before* the return does nothing since the returned filtered array isn't saved, and it also incorrectly searches for sub-strings.
4. Attempt to render `result` object in the render function, objects are invalid JSX

## Solution

1. Skip the `.then((values) => Promise.all(values.map((value) => value.json())))` step and just move on to accessing the JSON data.
2. Move the data fetching into a mounting `useEffect` hook so it's run only once.
3. Move the filter function inline in the render function and use string.prototype.includes to search.
4. Based on other properties rendered and what is left on the `result` object I'll assume you probably wanted to render the `email` property.

Code:

```
function Search() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const urls = [
      "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments",
      "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=1"
    ];

    Promise.all(
      urls.map((url) =>
        fetch(url)
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((data) => setResults(data))
          .catch((error) => console.log("There was a problem!", error))
      ),
      []
    );
  }, []);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setInput(e.target.value.toLowerCase());
  };

  return (
    <div className="search" htmlFor="search-input">
      <input
        type="text"
        name="query"
        value={input}
        id="search"
        placeholder="Search"
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      {results
        .filter((i) => i.name.toLowerCase().includes(input))
        .map((result, index) => {
          return (
            <div className="results" key={index}>
              <h2>{result.name}</h2>
              <p>{result.body}</p>
              {result.email}
            </div>
          );
        })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit how-do-i-fetch-search-results-from-multiple-api-using-reactjs]